# Consider three mutually independent classifiers, A, B, C, with equal error probabilities:

Tags: machine-learning, probability, ensemble-learning

**Here's the problem:**

> Consider three mutually independent classifiers, A, B, C, with equal error probabilities:
>
> Pr(errA) = Pr(errB) = Pr(errC) = t
>
> Let D be another classifier that takes the majority vote of A, B, and C.
>
> • What is Pr(errD)?
>
> • Plot Pr(errD) as a function of t.
>
> • For what values of t, the performance of D is better than any of the other three classifiers?

---

---

**My questions are:**

**(1)** I couldn't figure out the error probability of D. I thought it would be 1 minus alpha (1 - α), but I am not sure.

**(2)** How to plot t(Pr(errD))? I assume without finding Pr(errD) then I can plot it.

**(3)** Here as well, I couldn't figure it out. Comparatively, how should I determine the performance of D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, your problem can be formulated with simple terms without any ensemble learning.

Given that `D` is the result of a vote by 3 classifiers, `D` is wrong if and only if at most one of the estimators is right.

`A,B,C` are independent, so:

- the probability of none being right is t^3
- the probability of one being right while the other two are wrong is 3(1-t)t^2 (the factor 3 is because there are three ways to achieve this)

So P(errD) = t^3 + 3(1-t)t^2 = -2t^3 + 3t^2

You should be able to plot this as a function of t in the interval [0:1] without too many difficulties.

As for your third question, just solve P(errA) - P(errD) >0 (this means that the error probability of D is smaller than for A and so that its performance is better). If you solve this, you should find that the condition is t<0.5.

To come back to ensemble learning, note that the assumption of independence between your estimators is usually not verified in practice.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MaximeKan!
I was stuck with this problem.

Comment: Glad it helped! :)